# Heroku with Spring - when tomcat port overridden then app crashes

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, heroku

I'm trying to override random generated tomcat port by heroku. I am doing it like this:

web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=8080 -jar ./backend/target/backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

and it wokrs:

```
 app[web.1]: INFO 4 --- [main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''app[web.1]: INFO 4 --- [main] app.Main: Started Main in 6.746 seconds (JVM running for 7.788)
```

but then heroku crashes immediately (on default port it works):

```
State changed from starting to crashed at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET dyno= connect= service= status=503
```

Any suggestion would be really helpful. Is it possible to see more heroku logs because those are not really informative.

link to github: https://github.com/piotrkosinski1992/haro-poker.git

Comment: Isn't Heroku going to want to tell it which port to listen to?

Comment: But I need to know the port in order to connect my embedded angular app. I've established connection over websockets and locally I am pointing from angular to port 8080. When heroku changes port, then connection with frontend doesn't work

Comment: If the Angular app is being served by the backend, it can make relative requests. If it isn't, it can't hit the server by port in Heroku anyway; the client isn't running on the same machine, and Heroku only exposes one app.

Comment: When it comes to Rest requests it works using relative paths. but I have problem with websocket connection: wss://localhost:8080/players/add. When i use relative path I get: Error: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL '/players/add' is invalid.

Comment: You'll need to build the websocket URL from the current URL, you can do that with something like https://github.com/pivotal/postfacto/blob/559b72d257b526ebac11f094487696edaf0f5457/web/src/helpers/websockets.js

Comment: I've solved this issue replacing localhost:8080 in websocket url with 'window.location.host'. It dynamically detects url. Thank you all for help